# Proving correctness of pseudorandom generator construction given existing pseudorandom generator

Tags: random-number-generator

Say if I have a given pseudorandom generator G which **takes a k-bit input and outputs a 3k-bit number**.

How should I show that a specific construction using this pseudorandom generator is valid?

For example, if I want a generator which **takes a 2k-bit input and output a 3k-bit number**. Is the following scheme valid?

```
1. split the 2k-bit input into two half
2. passes the two half through the given generator G to get two 3k-bit numbers
3. XOR the two numbers to output the final 3k-bit number.
```

Comment: Well, what properties do you want to prove? One problem I see with your proposal is that, say $A$ and $B$ are k-bit inputs. If I put $A|B$ (where $|$ is concatenation) into your proposed system, the output will be the same as if I put $B|A$ in. I.e., $f(A|B)=f(B|A)$. This may or may not be an issue though depending on the properties you want (and the properties of the original generator $G$).

Comment: What's the definition of _valid_? Also, how is G _given_? As an explicit algorithm as implementable on a Turing Machine? As an explicit combination of ideal primitives/random oracles? Or is it just named and assumed valid?

Answer (score 4):

Call your original ($k$-to-$3k$ bit) PRG $G$ and your construction $G'$.

Let $\mathcal{U}_t$ denote the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}^t$. Then $G'$ is a PRG as long as the distributions $\mathcal{U}_{3k}$ and $G'(\mathcal{U}_{2k})$ are indistinguishable with effort polynomial in $k$; see [this reference](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/Pseudorandomness_generator).

Distribution $G'(\mathcal{U}_{2k})$ is just $G(\mathcal{U}_k) \oplus G(\mathcal{U}_k)$, where the two occurrences of $\mathcal{U}_k$ in the latter expression are independent. By the PRG property of $G$ applied to the first term, the distribution is indistinguishable from $\mathcal{U}_{3k} \oplus G(\mathcal{U}_k)$.

Since $\mathcal{U}_t \oplus \mathcal{D}$ is distributed identically to $\mathcal{U}_t$, for any independent distribution $\mathcal{D}$, we get the desired result.

---

I find this question a bit odd though. If all you want is a $2k$-to-$3k$ PRG constructed from a $k$-to-$3k$ PRG, then what about the following simpler construction: given $2k$ bits, throw away the first half and run the second half through the $k$-to-$3k$ PRG?

Comment: But a distinguisher for G' is trivial when the input is malleable! If the two input halves are equal, the output is all zero. I stand by my opinion the problem is ill-defined for lack of definition of _valid_ and _given_.

Comment: The definition of "pseudorandom generator" is very standard (e.g., [here](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/Pseudorandomness_generator)). There is no requirement for non-malleability of PRGs, whatever that would mean.

In the PRG distinguishing game, input to the PRG is chosen *randomly* and the output is given to the distinguisher. The case you are worried about (two halves being equal) happens with negligible probability ($2^{-k}$) and hence does not compromise the pseudorandomness of $G'$.

Comment: @Mikero: Yes, under a distinguishing game where input is random, G' is secure when G is, for some suitable asymptotic definition of secure, like "with effort polynomial in $k$ for an arbitrary small odd of success"; and your proof is sound. I was unaware this was implied by "pseudorandom generator". Change the answer (preferably clarifying that or linking to a reference, perhaps adding an explicit "with effort polynomial" before "in $k$" to prevent me reading "with effort in 2 to the $k$") and the answer's score will raise by 2.

Comment: @Mikero: I took the liberty to do what I suggested; feel free to revert.